# jQuery: Get id from selector which is inside a variable

Tags: jquery, variables, selector

I have a  #pdfcontainer which is inside divs #main and #pdfmain. I'm using a variable, because I use the same div many times:

```
var $pdfcontainer = $('#main #pdfmain #pdfcontainer');
```

Inside the #pdfcontainer I have  #delete which I want to access for various reasons. So how do I get it using the variable and without typing the whole $('#main ...') all over again? I don't just want to use selector $('#delete') because on my site it's much slower that way.

Thnx already!

- Antti

Comment: You are aware that you **shouldn't** use the same "*id*" more than once, right?

Comment: *"I don't just want to use selector $('#delete') because on my site it's much slower that way."* That doesn't make sense to me at all. jQuery's selector engine usually starts with the rightmost part of the selector anyway, and so it should be looking up `#delete` as a first step *anyway* (and then checking to make sure it's got the right lineage). What is it about your site that makes looking up an ID on its own somehow slower than looking it up and then walking the lineage?

Comment: @ifaour: Not shouldn't, ***mustn't***. :-)

Comment: I wasn't aware of that.. why should i not use the same id? :(

Comment: @AnttiQ: `id` values must be unique on a page: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute If you want to give the same name-like-thing to multiple elements, you usually want a `class`.

Comment: oh yea that.. yes I only use unique id's on elements.. eg. i have only one #delete :)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I get faster speeds (in microseconds :) when defining accurate place of the div eg. $('#main #pdfmain #pdfcontainer #delete') vs. just $('#delete')

Comment: @AnttiQ: I'd love to see a sample and some benchmarks. That just doesn't fit with how IDs work and how jQuery's selector engine works. I'm not saying it's not possible, just that it's very surprising and so I'd like to see it in action if it's really true.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: It must be browser dependent. The Sizzle engine won't play a role at all in browsers that support `qsa`, so it will come down to the individual `qsa` implementation. In non-`qsa` browsers, I would think you'd be right that `$('#delete')` would be faster.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I'm only using javascript microseconds on function's start and end and then comparing the results.. The site is huge and the speed comparison is about 9-11ms vs. 25-28ms. I'm not saying that it's an accurate result :) and I might be wrong about the whole thing.. maybe it really doesn't matter if I just use $('#delete')

Comment: @patrick: Yeah, but in browsers that support qsa, I still find it very hard to believe that it causes any measurable *improvement* in performance. Still, the code paths for `$('#delete')` and anything more complex *are* different, so... I'd just like to see some evidence of a measurable gain.

Comment: @AnttiQ: Understood. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify `$pdfcontainer` as context to your selector like this:

```
$("#delete", $pdfcontainer)
```

Make sure that you have only one item with unique ids, for example, you should have id `#delete` assigned to only one element.

Answer (score 0):

`$($pdfcontainer + " #delete")` should work, if you declare your variable as a string `var $pdfcontainer = "#id #id2 #id3";`. Using the variable in place of the actual string doesn't mean you can't add more to the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdfcontainer.find('#delete');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `pdfcontainer.find("#delete)` 
enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$pdfcontainer.find('#delete');
```

Comment: I googled a bit and couple of sites say that .find is faster than using a context. Is this true?

Comment: @AnttiQ: `$("#delete", $pdfcontainer)` runs through some test, and ultimately gets converted to `$pdfcontainer.find('#delete')`, so yes.